# Include layout in view programmatically within a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

Alright so I have a fragment and I'd like to include, within its' xml file another layout which is programmatically inflated

Fragment:

```
public class zGoal_Fragment extends Fragment{

    private LinearLayout todayView;
    private View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_goal_view, container, false);
        todayView = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.todayView);

        return view;
    }
}
```

xml's file for fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/todayView"
>
</LinearLayout>
```

and xml layout I want included within the above xml programmatically:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/goalEditLayout"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          android:background="@color/test_color_two"
>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried a couple different methods all of which led to " on a null object reference" errors...

plz help :))

Comment: I have added an answer for your query. You could either use ViewStubs or even better, use include tag and add your layout of another file inside the target xml file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the solution which you are looking for are Android ViewStubs. These are dynamically inflated layouts.

For more information you could refer these :

[How to use View Stub in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577777/how-to-use-view-stub-in-android)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html

However, if you **don't** wish to inflate one layout inside another during **runtime**, you could try this the **include** tag:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/todayView">

         <include layout="@layout/your_layout_file_name"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In case our answers helped you, don't forget to upvote and mark them as correct (arrow and tick mark beside answers). :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
LinearLayout child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.goalEditLayout, null);
todayView.addView(child);
```

Edit:
Inside onCreateView:

```
LinearLayout inflatedLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.goalEditLayout, todayView, true);
```

Comment: i may be wrong but getLayoutInflater() in a fragment cannot be called without a bundle parameter. :/